# export xml file with php

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework

I have data  to export in an xml file.For this reason, I use a `DOMDocument` object with `utf-8` encoding.
All special characters are encoded except apostrophe and double quotes.

**Before export** : `<p>"don't like"</p>`

**After export** : `&lt;p&gt;don't like &lt;/p&gt;`

**My snippet** :

```
$xml_file = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml_file->formatOutput = true;
 ....

$xml_file->save($file_path);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please puts the full code for generate XML structure.

Comment: i like that the apostrophe and the doule quotes  will be encoding:
apostrophe -> &apos;  
doublequotes->&quot;

Comment: DOMDocument only encoded characters if it is needed for wellformed XML.

Comment: try using html_entity_decode(); function

Comment: i want the opposite of html_entity_decode()

Comment: @Abderrahmen The opposite of `html_entity_decode()` is certainly `htmlentities`. 

Example of usage :

`$str = htmlentities($inputString, ENT_QUOTES);`